# Why is the makefile for this program I am trying to download not working? Is it an issue with the access to the $PETSC_DIR?

Tags: makefile, compilation, dependencies, petsc

I have been trying to follow the instructions to build an executable file called CrunchTope, and unfortunately every time I enter `make` into my BASH shell Mac terminal after updating it to the latest version using git pull and installing PETSc, it reads

> "bash-3.2$ make
> make: *** No rule to make target `crunchtype.o', needed by` CrunchMain'.  Stop."

in my terminal. When I look at the makefile for CrunchTope, seemingly there are instructions provided at the very end of the makefile:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

CrunchMain : ${OBJSF} #chkopts
    -${FLINKER} -o CrunchTope ${OBJSF} ${PETSC_FORTRAN_LIB} ${PETSC_LIB} ${FFLAGS}
```

And presumably these would allow the makefile to proceed. But when I check `"${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables"` for example, it says permission denied even though I've tried altering the permissions already. Also, it says it cannot find the 'include' function.

So what would be the root cause of this issue? The makefile should be working, it works for other Macs, and I have triple checked that the PETSc directory works and is installed properly. But it seemingly cannot overcome the "no rule" issue.

Apologies for my lack of understanding on this issue, I am quite new to this! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time

As I said earlier, I have tried changing the permissions of the

${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

documents so that it does not read permission denied when I try to call upon them in the terminal, so that hopefully they can be accessed in the makefile and allow the building to proceed, but this did not seem to work.

Comment: The error message you report suggests that your distribution of the software is incomplete.  However, in light of the fact that you say you had to fix permissions on some files, it is also possible that you need to fix more permissions.  `make` needs read and execute (traverse) permissions on *all* directories in the source tree, read permission on substantially *all* regular files within, and write permission at least on the  top source directory.  And of course, when I say `make` needs permission I mean *you* do, as the user running `make`.